# How can i resolve this problem on Python anywere

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I created a Telegram bot who creates news for a football RP, when you enter the input of the player name it should search on google the image and take the first image that appears but I have a console error even if google is in python anywhere white list. here is the error:(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

here is the lines of code

```
link = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+nome+'%20'+cognome+'%20football'+'&tbm=isch'

        response = requests.get(link)

        ans = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, 'lxml')

        imgs= ans.findAll('img')

        image_url = str(imgs[len(imgs)//2]).split('src="')[1][:-3]

        photo = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream=True).raw)

        giocatore = nome+' '+cognome

        news_message = get_news_message(giocatore, squadra, costo, stipendio, epicità)

        bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo, caption=news_message)

        return
```

When i enter the player for examples Cristiano Ronaldo it should send the first image on google but i get the precedent error